# Does "size scale field" in QGIS actually work?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm having mixed results with the 'size scale field' aka graduated symbols in QGIS.

Some forum posts out there say this feature is broken - others can get it to work.

Comment: Maybe you could be a bit more specific about the cases when it does not work for you. If the problem is reproducible, a bug ticket should be filed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to make it work. Here's the post

[Tutorial: Styling Vector Data in QGIS Using Size-Scale Field](http://qgis.spatialthoughts.com/2012/02/styling-vector-data-in-qgis-using-size.html)

I tested in QGIS 1.8 as well and it works fine too.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, data-defined properties are more reliable than the size-scale field. Give it a try if you are using QGIS 2.6 or higher.